# Tripped breaker

Tags: electrical

We bought a mobile home with a master bedroom that consists of an ensuite and master bathroom. The three rooms combined are 20 feet by 20 feet with their own electrical breakers. We bought our home new and have lived in it now 9 years. My question is this, the breaker in the sleeping area is tripping, is it possible it is beginning to wear out?

Comment: It seems more likely that it would be something to do with the electrical load in the room. Are you running a window A/C or something else with a large draw there?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Yes, we have a stand-up A/C but we have had it for many years and have never had a problem. The tripping began in the winter when we didn't have the portable A/C plugged in.

Comment: Did you have a heater plugged in when the tripping started? Does it trip randomly, or only when you plug a bunch of stuff in?  Do you have any trouble with mice?  Did anything change when the problem started (new devices, new wiring, new photos hung, etc. )?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, they DO do that when they get old, especially if they've had a number of VALID trips. I've replaced a lot of old failing breakers that couldn't sustain even half their marked rating.

It's easy & cheap to check that by replacing the breaker with a new one of identical ratings. If the NEW one trips, you DO have a problem that needs resolution. If not, you're done & can forget it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, we will purchase a new breaker and try it out. By doing the work ourselves can we potentially lose our fire insurance?

Comment: I don't imagine that you would, since a breaker replacement doesn't involve rerouting or resizing any wires - only one wire need ever be disconnected, and it's reconnected to the replacement breaker in exactly the same way it was disconnected from the old one. DO be careful in there. When you unplug the old one, the metal bar it attaches to is LIVE, with very little protection between it and you. Best do the job with the MAIN breaker turned off. It'll take only a few minutes, and it's easy to do with a flashlight.

Comment: CAVEAT: If you have an old breaker box, you may have trouble finding a breaker of the right type to fit it. Local hardware stores sometimes stock units that the major electrical supply houses don't, since they know what brands were commonly installed in their area.